# How to style data using css grid?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to fetch data from API and need to display data in a grid format using CSS grid. I have fetched data from api but when I use grid it is showing data in one column and comma(,) in another column. Below is my code.
[This is final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Poi9.png)

[This is my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewePX.png)

```js
const url = "https://dummyapi.io/data/v1/user";

const getAllPosts = async() => {
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "app-id": "63a7f2379ffe7f84dc337b03"
    }
  })
  return response.json();
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async() => {
  const allPosts = await getAllPosts();
  const displayPost = allPosts.data.map(post => {
    return `
        <div class="post">
            <div class="image">
                <img src=${post.picture} alt="Profile picture" class="ppic" />
            </div>
            <div class="post-text">
                <p>${post.id}</p>
                <p>${post.title.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + post.title.slice(1)} ${post.firstName} ${post.lastName}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        `
  });
  document.querySelector("#all-posts").insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", displayPost);
});
```

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.ppic {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.post {
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section class="container" id="all-posts" style="grid-auto-flow: row;"></section>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The map() method **creates a new array**. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

If you look at your html created by your function, you will see that you have your two columns as espected, but one of them contains only commas (visible in your picture) [image]

This is because your `displayPost` variable before `insertAdjacentHTML` looks something like this :

```
['<div class="post">...</div>', '<div class="post">...</div>', '<div class="post">...</div>']
```

And what you want is this

```
<div class="post">...</div> <div class="post">...</div> <div class="post">...</div>
```

**Here is your code fixed :**

```js
const url = "https://dummyapi.io/data/v1/user";

const getAllPosts = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "app-id": "63a7f2379ffe7f84dc337b03"
    }
  });
  return response.json();
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async () => {
  const allPosts = await getAllPosts();
  let displayPost = "";
  allPosts.data.forEach(function (post) {
    displayPost += `
        <div class="post">
            <div class="image">
                <img src=${post.picture} alt="Profile picture" class="ppic" />
            </div>
            <div class="post-text">
                <p>${post.id}</p>
                <p>${
                  post.title.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + post.title.slice(1)
                } ${post.firstName} ${post.lastName}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        `;
  });
  document
    .querySelector("#all-posts")
    .insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", displayPost);
});
```

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.ppic {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.post {
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section class="container" id="all-posts" style="grid-auto-flow: row;"></section>
```